# Translation of BlockBase (ConfigurablePluginInterface)

Tags: blocks, i18n-l10n

```
  public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::blockForm($form, $form_state);

    // Retrieve existing configuration for this block.
    $config = $this->getConfiguration();

    // Add a form field to the existing block configuration form.
    $form['Heading'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Heading'),
      '#default_value' => isset($config['heading']) ? $config['heading'] : '',
    );
```

'#default_value' => isset($config['heading']) ? $config['heading'] : '',

can this thing be translated? And how?
I use it to display a text to site users

Answer (score 0):

The key was in creating mymodule.schema.yml in mymodule/config/schema/mymodule.schema.yml

with content of a kind

```
block.settings.myblock:
  type: block_settings
  mapping:
    Heading:
      type: text
      label: 'Heading'
      translatable: true
```

also

```
$config = $this->getConfiguration();
```

is not needed
using

```
$this->configuration['heading']
```

insted

\core\modules\system\src\Plugin\Block\SystemBrandingBlock.php -- is a good example